# List index out of range and giving the output ans still

Tags: python, list, indexing

`

```
list1  = [0,[1, 2, 3], [7, [5, 6]], [7], [8, 9]]
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
ans=[]
i = 0
n = len(list1)-1
while(n-2):
    print(type(list1))
    condition = (type(list1[i]) == int)
    if condition == True:
        ans.append(list1[i])
       
    else:
        
        for j in range(0, len(list1[i])):
            condition1 = (type(list1[i][j]) == list)
            if condition1 == True:
                for k in range(0, len(list1[i][j])-1):
                    ans.append(list1[i][j][k])
            else:
                ans.append(list1[i][j])
    
    i+=1
        
print(ans)
```

[Can anyone help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NVe8.png)`

I was trying to simplify the list and i used list for saving it but WHy Index of range. and Still my ans is getting save and giving the right output.

Comment: Can you tell us what's the goal of this program?  What do you mean *simplify* it?

Answer (score 0):

There are **5** items in **list1** (see below):

```
0
[1, 2, 3]
[7, [5, 6]]
[7]
[8, 9]
```

Your code is incrementing beyond the index of this list

**To flatten the list:**

```
list1  = [0,[1, 2, 3], [7, [5, 6]], [7], [8, 9]]

def flatten_list(my_list):
    is_not_Flat = True
    my_list = [item for sublist in [item if type(item)==list else [item] for item in my_list] for item in sublist]
    
    while is_not_Flat:
        for item in my_list:
            if type(item) == list:
                my_list = flatten_list(my_list)
        
        is_not_Flat = False
        
    return my_list
                

print(flatten_list(list1))
```

#### Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```